# How to solve enabling feature issue in OrchardCore cms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, orchardcms

I am trying to build a OrchardCore CMS feature using this official tutorial

https://orchardcore.readthedocs.io/en/dev/docs/guides/add-admin-menu/

When I enable the features inside the CMS admin panel the server responded with a HTTP-statuscode 405 and a white page.
I looked in the log files but cannot find anything about it.
So, to figure out something more, I did a fresh install of the CMS using this command from the same tutorial.

```
dotnet new occms -n MySite
```

And again, I am not able to enable features. Disabling works, but, when I try to enable it again it doesn't work.

The DLL version of OrchardCore is: 1.0.0-rc1-10004

Does anyone know the solution?

Thanks in advance,
Jordy

Comment: Anything of interest in `App_Data\logs`?

Comment: Yes, there is a log file, but nothing interesting in there. Just one line which is not related to this issue. The cms is not working out-of-the-box which is very strange.

Comment: Anything else than the 405 status in headers returned from the server? Normally the server is supposed to provide information about what methods are allowed when it responds with a 405.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot. The browser makes a GET-request and the server responded with "allow: post" header. I installed the docker image - and there it's making a POST-request and working. But, how can I get it working using that tutorial (using Visual Studio)?

Comment: Both controller actions, enable and disable, can be found on the `AdminController` in `OrchardCore.Modules/OrchardCore.Features/Controllers`. They're both marked for accepting only POST. The buttons are really `A` tags, which do GET unless script intercepts the click and transforms that into a POST, which is exactly what the `TheAdmin/Assets/js/admin.js` script is supposed to be doing for all links marked `itemprop="RemoveUrl"`. So in a nutshell, look at your browser's F12 javascript console for errors. I'd bet this script crashed for some reason.

Comment: I looked for javascript errors already, but, there is no error. In the meanwhile, I get it working will write it down in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Bertrand (see above) I was able to figure out what was not going well.

To troubleshoot, I installed the project templates, using the same steps, on another machine - and it was working properly. Which looks strange to me.
So, what I did was removing the project templates from the machine where I was working on, and re-installed them using this command. Below I will describe the steps I did.

1. First was removing the OrchardCore.ProjectTemplates template

   C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v3.0.100\packages\orchardcore.projecttemplates.1.0.0-rc1-10004.nupkg
2. Resetting my installation to initial state and removing all templates (see https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/961#issuecomment-309158932).

   dotnet new --debug:reinit
3. Re-installing the OrchardCore.ProjectTemplates

   dotnet new -i OrchardCore.ProjectTemplates::1.0.0-*

After taking this steps my OrchardCore installation is working properly.